# Conflict between Boostrap and Chosen Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the amazing [Chosen Plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) with this [Adaptative CSS that makes the Chosen more Bootstrap friendly](https://code.google.com/p/clients-oriented-ftp/source/browse/trunk/includes/js/chosen/chosen.bootstrap.css?r=418) and the [Bootstrap CSS Framework](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation) and my specific problem relies on the **Form Control Validation** from **Bootstrap**. According to the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation), you simply add the class `has-error` to an element and

> Any .control-label, .form-control, and .help-block within that element will receive the validation styles.

The problem is that the Chosen is not any of the above, it's just a div. I'm looking for ideas on how to wrap the Chosen plugin on the `has-error` class to be able to provide an "invalid state".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet to properly utilize the bootstrap utility classes (in this case has-error) in conjunction with the html that chosen.js injects:

```
select.form-control + .chosen-container.chosen-container-single.has-error .chosen-single {
  border-color: #a94442;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
}
```

As you can see we've added the utility class to our root element which can be accessed by using the chosen id convention, where chosen takes the input id (#foo), appends _chosen (#foo_chosen) and assigns it to the root element (.chosen-container).